# Converting a complicated list to data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list

```
my_list = list("1" = list(year = 1900, values = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
         another_attribute = "hello"), "2" = list(year = 1901,
         values = c(11,12,13,14,15), another_attribute = "thankyou"))
my_list
$`1`
$`1`$year
[1] 1900

$`1`$values
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$`1`$another_attribute
[1] "hello"


$`2`
$`2`$year
[1] 1901

$`2`$values
[1] 11 12 13 14 15


$`2`$another_attribute
[1] "thankyou"
```

I want to convert this to a data.frame or matrix where values are the rows and year is the row name e.g.

```
my_df = rbind(my_list$'1'$values, my_list$'2'$values)
```

if possible with row names as the years

```
rownames(my_df) = c(my_list$'1'$year, my_list$'2'$year)
my_df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
1900    1    2    3    4    5
1901   11   12   13   14   15
```

I want to avoid a loop statement, I can pull out each attribute in a loop but I want to know if there is another snazzier way. As this is a big list.

Comment: Not sure if this is intentional, but `another_attribute = "thankyou"` isn't inside the second list item, so the first list item has length 3, but the second list item has length 2

Comment: @Suren I would suggest not to edit examples on behalf of OP. Sometimes, it maybe obvious (like in this case) that OP mistyped something but still let OP correct it's own example. We can comment and clarify further if any doubt. Let's not assume things on behalf of OP.

Comment: @RonakShah I can see that there can be such situations where asking the OP is the best thing to do, but do you really think this is one?

Comment: @Suren As I said, let's not assume on behalf of OP. The best is to let OP correct it's own example. In such cases, we could leave a comment and if we are adding an answer add an extra line denoting the assumption same as what @ thalatemail did. This is just my opinion though :)

Comment: @RonakShah I do see what you mean (I think - I did just fixed `my_df = rbind(my_list$'1'$values, my_list$'1'$values)`) :). I do acknowledge that there is a slight chance that initial one may not have been a mistake - just that it is very very likely a mistake.

Comment: Yeah thanks for noticing that it was suppose to be in there. An error on my behalf. Thanks for spotting and editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your example list must be corrected:

```
my_list = list("1" = list(year = 1900, values = c(1,2,3,4,5),
another_attribute = "hello"), "2" = list(year = 1901,values =
c(11,12,13,14,15), another_attribute = "thankyou"))
```

Then you write for one element of your list of lists (so the first inner list) a function which does exactly what you want.

```
entry2df <- function(el) {
  df <- as.data.frame(t(el$values))
  rownames(df) <- el$year
  df
}
```

And then you use `lapply` (for applying the function over each element of your list and collect the result in a results-list) and perform `Reduce` with `rbind` to bind those list of single data frames row by row to one data frame.

```
Reduce(rbind, lapply(my_list, entry2df))
```

The result:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1900  1  2  3  4  5
1901 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lapply` to extract both year and values

```
library(magrittr)
lapply(my_list, "[", "values") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(unlist(lapply(my_list, "[","year") )) %>% 
  t()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map` to piece the parts together, `rbind` to a matrix and make a data.frame:

```
data.frame(do.call(Map, c(rbind, my_list) ))

#  year values.1 values.2 values.3 values.4 values.5 another_attribute
#1 1900        1        2        3        4        5             hello
#2 1901       11       12       13       14       15          thankyou
```

Where `my_list` was fixed to put `another_attribute` in both the first and second lists:

```
my_list <- structure(list(`1` = structure(list(year = 1900, values = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5), another_attribute = "hello"), .Names = c("year", 
"values", "another_attribute")), `2` = structure(list(year = 1901, 
    values = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15), another_attribute = "thankyou"), .Names = c("year", 
"values", "another_attribute"))), .Names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Nice. But, I think the request is just the values in rows ("where values are the rows").

Comment: @Suren - the `values` have been put into rows. I don't know what else is required.

Comment: I thought not have the `another_attribute`. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
mat <- t(sapply(my_list,`[[`,"values"))
rownames(mat) <- sapply(my_list,`[[`,"year")

mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# 1900    1    2    3    4    5
# 1901   11   12   13   14   15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Extracting the values
my_df <- t(sapply(1:length(my_list), function(x) my_list[[x]]$values))
my_df
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]   11   12   13   14   15

# Making it a data.frame
my_df <- as.data.frame(my_df)

# Assining the correct row names
rownames(my_df) <- sapply(1:length(my_list), function(x) my_list[[x]]$year)
my_df
#       V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1900  1  2  3  4  5
# 1901 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
my_list %>% 
  map_df(~.x %>% 
             as_tibble %>%
             select(year, values) %>%
             mutate(rn = row_number())  )  %>% 
  spread(rn, values) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  column_to_rownames('year') %>%
  as.matrix %>%
  `colnames<-`(., NULL)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#1900    1    2    3    4    5
#1901   11   12   13   14   15
```